# C# vs C++ - Types, inheritance and vtable

Tags: c#, c++, inheritance, types, object-slicing

I'm having trouble understanding what causes this difference between C++ and C#.

First we have an example in which the base class contains a virtual function.

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int super;
public:
    virtual int f() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int extraA;
    int f(){ return 1; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived *d = new Derived();

    std::vector<Base*> v;
    v.push_back(d);

    for(int i=0; i < v.size() ;i++)
    {
            // Output "Derived"
            std::cout << typeid(*v[i]).name() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is, as expected, "Derived".

If we remove f(), this no longer works. The output is "Base". Example:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int super;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int extraA;
};

int main()
{
    Derived *d = new Derived();

    std::vector<Base*> v;
    v.push_back(d);

    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    {
            // Output "Base"
            std::cout << typeid(*v[i]).name() << std::endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My understanding of this is, that having a virtual function causes the compiler to add a vptr to the object, which points to the vtable. The vtable contains the address of the correct function to invoke (Derived::f()) - (As well as type information of the object?)

Now for the interesting part - Comparison with C#. Here, "Base" and "Derived" are basically empty classes similar to the 2nd C++ example :

```
public static void Main()
{
        Derived d = new Derived();
        IList<Base> v = new List<Base>();
        mList.Add(d);

        for (int i = 0; i < v.Count; i++)
        {
            // Output: "Derived"
            System.Console.WriteLine(v.ElementAt(i).GetType()); 
        }
}
```

My question is thus: Is my understanding of the C++ part correct, and how does C# manage to correctly identify the type of the object when C++ doesn't?

Comment: This article might help you understand how this is implemented behind the scenes in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx -- see the section on object layout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's as you say: C++ enables runtime polymorphism and type identification only whenever your class has a `virtual` function, which means that (in common implementations) a `vptr` is added to the class (this is coherent with the philosophy of C++ "you don't pay for what you don't need").

> (As well as type information of the object?)

Yet, it's common to store a pointer to the RTTI record in the first slot of the vtable of a class - and I'd say that this is one of the reasons why the standard requires RTTI to work only if the class is polymorphic (although, as usual, this all is compiler-dependent).

By the way, RTTI is not necessary for virtual dispatch to work correctly, if you call a virtual function all the compiler has to do is to do a `call ptr` with the pointer taken from the correct slot of the vtable; the RTTI record is used only when checking the class hierarchy in `dynamic_cast` and when asking explicitly about the type of an object via `typeid`.

In C#, instead, every class is polymorphic by default and has reflection metadata associated to it, so there's no need to do anything particular to enable polymorphism/type identification.

Comment: @user1202032 This is the best answer, in your particular case it is mostly because C# use reflection like Matteo Italia said.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, runtime type information only really works on types where a parent class in your hierarchy has at least one virtual function. The "vtable" pointer points to the virtual function table as well as identifies the type. (In principle, at least, I can't remember how strictly the standard specifies how virtual functions should be implemented) If there are no virtual functions at all, that information is left out for efficiency.

In C# type information is always there, virtual functions or not.

Answer (score 2):

The differences between C++ and C# are deep and vast, and this is but a footnote in the encyclopaedia of differences.

Namely, in C#, every class must inherit from Object, which has virtual functions, so C# never, ever has the case where an object has no virtual functions. C++, however, does. Commonly. So in C++ there is nowhere to put the run-time type identification information.

Comment: IMO inheriting from object hasn't got much to do with this, all they did was decide that type information is always available, whether there are any virtual functions of not.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: The only place to put that type information is in the vtable.

Comment: @DeadMG, what's stopping you from having a vtable even for types that have no virtual methods?

Comment: @svick: C++ has a policy that doing so would be very wasteful.