# C# vs C++: inheritance specifics

Tags: c#, c++, inheritance, porting

What can be counted as a visible difference between C# and C++ OOP standard definitions? I'm especially interested in anything related to visibility of overloaded/overrided methods.

It seems that C# implements a subset of C++ inheritance order based of stack call order in a class chain; Is that true? Or C# OOP is something different from C++? (Of course, C# has native reflection support, but I'm more interested in finding issues related to inheritance or, probably, compositing).

Is there a well-known situation, in which `class N: .. class B: A { }` in C++ can't access the base class data (under any possible conditions) that is possible in C#?

---

I am strongly against recognizing this question as "already answered". Nothing on 'internal' was said, [abstract classes can't be clearly evaluated to C++ protected constructor / virtual constructor classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854778/abstract-class-vs-interface-in-c) (and the whole interface thing is different with C++). Thus, please don't close the bounty if I have the chance to open it - there surely must be more differences.

Comment: What do you mean by “C# implements a subset of C++ inheritance order based of stack call order in a class chain”? That sentence doesn’t make sense to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# vs C++ - Types, inheritance and vtable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727827/c-sharp-vs-c-types-inheritance-and-vtable)

Comment: @BassamAlugili That question is about one particular difference between inheritance of C# and C++.  This question is asking for *all* of the differences, making it "too broad" instead.

Comment: Define "any possible conditions". Knowing memory layout of the base class you can access memory it resides directly to read or change object's private members.

Answer (score 2):

`c++` supports Multiple inheritance, whereas C# doesn't that is probably the biggest differences.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you can find a whole book on this stuff. One big change is when defining a class in C#, you can only inherit from one base class. C++ you can inherit from multiple.

> Is there a well-known situation, in which class N: .. class B: A { }
>   in C++ can't access the base class data (under any possible
>   conditions) that is possible in C#?

If the base class is protected or public.

> The protected keyword is a member access modifier. A protected member
>   is accessible within its class and by derived class instances. (Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx)

Comment: following works in C++:

namespace XX {
 class Nest {
  protected:
  class Zero
  {
  protected:
   int xx;
  };

  class St : Zero {
  public:
   void Test() {
    xx = 1;
   }
  };
 };
}

Comment: I was referring to them in the sense that, the base class has protected members which are accessible through the derived class type. I've updated my answer @kagali-san